# How to force a GPRS connection instead of 3G or Wifi?

Tags: android, gprs

I am writing an application where I need to have specifically a GPRS connection, even if wifi or 3G (or better) is available. I have figured out how to disable wifi (by using `WifiManager`), however, I can't seem to find out how I can programmatically disable 3G and only use a GPRS connection, with equal effect as changing this manually in the device settings.

Is there a way to do this with code?

**UPDATE**: What I am looking for does not necessarily have to be in the public Android APIs. It might as well be in one of the undocumented APIs, or as a last resort, device-specific APIs, I just need something that works. However, I'd rather not have to root a device to use these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not just private APIs but that a 3rd party APK cannot get permission to modify such a setting.

As a result, doing so would require a rooted device in addition to reverse engineering private interfaces.

Comment: does this hold true until today?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know changing the type of the mobile network is not possible out from an app.

Comment: I know of at least one application which seems to have this capabiliy (namely the [Extended Controls](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.extendedcontrols) application), so I don't think it is impossible

Comment: @Frxstream - have you verified that on a non-rooted device?  "possible from an app" tends to refer to what Android is designed to allow apps to do, launching helper processes as the superuser not being a designed capability.

Answer (score 0):

In android framework, TelephonyManager is the object providing Telephony service to android application.
see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html 
The service do provide several methods to know state and information of your physical radio component.
**But there is no way to modify the way the physical radio component of your device do its job. Its a private logic of your device manufacturer that try to do its best to comply radiophony industrial standard and provide the best end user experience quality**

*This is an public api android point of view (over dalvik) answer, do not answer in context of private android api, nor native way nor root privileged way.*